# What should I put in as business requirements where only improvements to existing processes are required

Tags: requirements

I am writing system requirements for a tender.

Functional requirements consist of mostly improving the system (add/remove data fields, improve statistics and activity log, exchange more data with other systems) without adding any new processes.

What should I put in as business requirements? Can I leave that section empty if there is no new business process? It seems kind of pointless to describe processes which are already in production.

EDIT:
Example. 
Already existing business processes (BP):
BP1 - User opens application, enters data about applicant, application is approved.
BP2 - Select statistics about applicants data for local and international organizations.

In tender I add this Functional requirement (FR):
FR1 - add 200 new fields about applicant.
FR2 - add new data fields in statistics filters according to FR1.

BP1 and BP2 doesn't change from business perspective, only amount of data. 
Is it necessary to include in tender business process requirements such as:
BPR1 - add new data fields to application because of digitalization.
BPR2 - add new fields to a statistics because now we have more data in application and therefore we need more stats for local and international organizations. I'm writing super basic example to understand if this is even necessary to include description of business process which doesn't change. If I was a developer, I just add new fields in already existing application form and add new filter fields in already existing statistics filter, since both those processes already exist as they are needed. Only improvements to existing stuff.

Comment: does your form have any definitions or guidance as to what it means by Functional and Business requirements? They can mean different things at different companies

Comment: It is a state institution, no guidelines. In other tenders functional req are buttons, fields and stuff you can actually do and get in the system. Business req in those are new features like linking payments to a service, apply online, add new steps and statuses in work flow. I dont have any of that, same processes, same steps.

Comment: From your words *"What should I put in" - "Can I leave that section ..."* - I guess  you have a form in front of you given to you by someone else, with sections we here cannot know. So what do you expect from us? You need to ask the creator of the form what they expect from you to put in that fields.

Comment: the "creator" of this form is outsource firm and in no way related to my project or any other projects at the moment afaik (they did bad job). this is my first tender so i expect advice on what developers might want to see as a BP if there are no *new* BP .

Comment: @user3671635: so you already know "business requirements" means "business **process** requirements" in your context? This is not self-evident, you know?

Comment: In my text it is said "no new business **process**" which implies that

Comment: What you wrote literally, it gave me the impression this point is not really clear to you.  And if there is a specific section in the form, why do you think that section is only for *new*, addtional processes? Couldn't it be meant as a place for writing down modifications to existing processes?

Comment: There's no specific form how to write this document,it is just a template I chose from another project. There are no new BP so should I describe already existing process (BPR->"user enters data about applicant same as before only now more fields are added because of work digitalization") or should I ignore the fact that user enters data, just mention "add 200 new fields" (functional req). As Ewan mentioned, it's for fixed price estimation. As a develop. i am interested that 200 new fields are needed and doesnt matter why they are needed if they are added to already existing and working process

Answer (score 1):

There obviously is a need to have those additional fields. Find out why they are needed and who needs them. That is a requirement. Write down why they need the fields and you are good.

Comment: I think that OP is aware of that. The problem is whether it is sufficient or not. If no additional information is provided to an independent team, will it be able to estimate and organise the work (e.g testing all the existing BP with the additional work) ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say that if you are looking for a Fixed Price quote the most important things to include are:

- The technologies used
- Test coverage of existing tests
- Overview of the process to be changed
- Overview of the new process required (ie extra fields added to step 5)
- Key non functional requirements. ie performance
- Value to business of the process, how many people use it, how bad if it goes down etc

Essentially you are asking vendors to estimate how long it would take them to implement the change. The risk to them is that the some overlooked aspect makes the job 100 times more difficult.

So they will need to:

- Speak to developers who are experts in the technologies used AND who have done similar business processes before.
- Guess at what level of polish you require. ie will the software be running in a battleship where lives are on the line if it needs rebooting once in a year, or is it something bob in accounts runs once a month to make a report no-one reads